# How to setup ssh SOCKS proxy on another host instead of localhost?

Tags: ssh, centos5, socks

My MacBook (192.168.8.201) WIFI is off and the LAN assigned IP does not have internet access. A CentOS box (192.168.12.50) has internet access. So I setup an instant SSH SOCKS proxy to surf the web temporary by:

```
 ssh -fND localhost:30000 someone@192.168.12.50
```

Then I setup the SOCKS proxy of the LAN interface:

```
 SOCKS Proxy Server: 127.0.0.1:30000
```

Is it possible do similar setup but run the SOCKS Proxy on 192.168.12.50? Such that for some machine without ssh can still use SOCKS proxy from a remote host. So SOCKS proxy setting for my MacBook LAN becomes:

```
 SOCKS Proxy Server: 192.168.12.50:30000
```

and I don't need to run my own: `ssh -fND ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Peter Krumin's article [here](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/linux-socks5-proxy/):

```
ssh -f -N -D 0.0.0.0:1080 localhost
```

I agree this isn't ideal, so you may want to look at something like [Dante](http://www.inet.no/dante/). I believe [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) can do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by installing 3rd party software on your centOS box.

[Here](http://www.linuxexpert.ro/Linux-Tutorials/setup-ss5-socks-proxy.html) is a tutorial than can help

Comment: Omar, here on SF we generally prefer that people post more than just links off-site, as these can go stale.  If you can at least post a brief summary of what the linked article suggests, it helps your answer stay relevant - and be more likely to attract up-votes.